# Progress bar for JGraphX layout

Tags: layout, jprogressbar, jgraphx

Is it possible to use a progress bar with an `mxIGraphLayout`?  I have a graph that takes a non-trivial time to layout, and I would like the user to be able to see that, yes, something is happening.

Ideally, I would like something that I can interpret (even roughly) as a percent done, but there does not even seem to be a way to add any listeners that are called during the layout.

If it matters, I am using `mxOrganicLayout` but I might change in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The can be accomplished somewhat by extending `mxOrganicLayout` and overriding the following methods

```
    @Override
    public void execute(Object cell)
    {
        progress.setProgress(0);
        try
        {
            super.execute(cell);
        }
        finally
        {
            progress.setProgress(maxIterations);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void performRound()
    {
        progress.setNote("Iteration " + iteration);
        progress.setProgress(iteration);
        super.performRound();
    }

    final ProgressMonitor progress;
```

Obviously, you need to set `progress` at some point as well.  `execute` notifies the progress monitor that execution has started, and closes it when it is done.

`performRound` is called to do the actual updates, so incrementing the progress there will cause the progress bar to advance.